# Is nesting of futures an anti pattern?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

I have a `ListenableFuture` that I am creating like:

```
ListenableFuture<X> future1 = ...
ListenableFuture<X> future2 = ...
Futures.addCallback(future1, futureCallback, executor);
```

Now inside the `futureCallback` I do :

```
public void onSuccess(Object result) {
  Object f2 = future2.get();
  .
  .
  . <do something with f2>
}
```

Is it a bad thing to do a `.get()` call in a callback? I was told that I could get into a hung up state. Is that true and why would it so happen?
What is the alternative of achieving the same thing in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something more like:

[`whenAllSucceed`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#whenAllSucceed-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...-)`(future1, future2).run(...)`

The `Runnable` you pass to `run` will still have to call `future2.get`. Still, `whenAllComplete` has some advantages over the `addCallback` approach:

- The `addCallback` approach may require a thread to block on `future2.get` until `future2` is done. (This is at least a small waste of resources. If you run out of threads, your code may hang. Or you might try to create a new thread and run out of memory.) With `whenAllComplete`, your `Runnable` won't run until both input futures are done, so `future2.get` will not block.
- `whenAllComplete` returns a `Future`. You can use this to check for errors. And if you cancel it, it will cancel both input futures.

Note also that `whenAllSucceed` will log if multiple inputs fail. This isn't always desirable. If you don't want the logging, you might prefer [`whenAllComplete`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#whenAllComplete-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...-). (Hopefully someday we will [provide a way to turn off the logging](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2134).)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `.get()` call in a callback is outright usual -- it's what you want to do most of the time -- but a more standard pattern is to, instead, use [`transform`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transform-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-com.google.common.base.Function-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) or [`transformAsync`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#transformAsync-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture-com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) to pass in a function that takes the result directly.

Comment: I can pass a Function to a callback. But how/when will it be invoked? Can you give an example?

Comment: `transform` and `transformAsync` will start evaluating the `Function` as soon as the input future completes, and will output the result into the output future as soon as they finish.

Answer (score 0):

Doing blocking operation in callback (e.g. future.get) destroys the idea of asynchronous programming, turning asynchronous program in ordinary multithreaded. So this is indeed an antipattern.
It's OK, however, to call get() if you are sure it would not block.
If you want a callback which waits for 2 asynchronous results, you can use CompletableFuture instead:

```
CompletableFuture<X> future1 = ...
CompletableFuture<X> future2 = ...
CompletableFuture future3 = future1.thenCombineAsync(future 2, futureCallback, executor);
```